# type-only imports conflict with no-duplicate-imports eslint rule

Tags: typescript, eslint, typescript-eslint, type-only-import-export

I have a `PropsTypes.ts` file like this:

```
export interface ImageSrc { url: string; originUrl: string }

export default interface PropsType {
  images: Array<ImageSrc> | Array<string>;
  visible: boolean;
  activeIndex?: number;
  showPagination?: boolean;
  maxScale?: number;
  minScale?: number;
  onChange?: Function;
  onClose?: Function;
}
```

I am using [type-only-imports-and-export](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-8.html#type-only-imports-and-export) feature of TypeScript 3.8.

```
import type PropsType from './PropsType';
import type { ImageSrc } from './PropsType';
```

But eslint will throw an error:

> './PropsType' imported multiple times. eslint(import/no-duplicates)

I expected eslint should satisfy this rule for type-only imports and export.
Is there a way to satisfy this eslint rule without disabling it?

Comment: https://github.com/benmosher/eslint-plugin-import/blob/master/docs/rules/no-duplicates.md

Answer (score 2):

Use `@typescript-eslint/no-duplicate-imports` rule from `typescript-eslint` plugin: https://typescript-eslint.io/rules/no-duplicate-imports/

Answer (score 0):

You can use like this import both PropsType and PropsType

```
import type { PropsType , ImageSrc } from './PropsType';
```